# How to create a simple redirect route in OpenShift without the whole process of deploying an Apache container?

Tags: routes, openshift

I have three domains where one of them is the actual application and the remaining two of them should point to the first one with a simple HTTP 301 redirect (they should not serve the actual application). So, if the user accesses any route below `domainB.com` or `domainC.com`, a simple HTTP 301 response should be presented, directing statically to `domainA.com` (`Location: https://domainA.com`).

Is there any simple way for such a use case without configuring an own application with a separate ImageStream, BuildConfig, Service, Route, etc. just for this very simple use case? Is the OpenShift router being able to handle that scenario?

Comment: @sandrooco No, unfortunately not. In the end, I just deployed a simple container doing the redirect..

Answer (score -1):

I think you can create 3 routes for your 3 domains.

Comment: And how would I configure those routes so that route B redirects to route A?